# How to use -lco options in gdal_contour?

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql, ogr, contour

I'm trying to create contours from geotiff raster with gdal_contour. My output format is Postgresql and I would like to ovewrite the existing table.

When I do:
**gdal_contour -a 1 -f PostgreSQL -i 50 -nln new_isolines dem.tif "PG:host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mybase user=postgres password=postgres"**
I get:
**ERROR 1: Layer new_isolines already exists, CreateLayer failed.
Use the layer creation option OVERWRITE=YES to replace it.**

But when I do:
**gdal_contour -a 1 -f PostgreSQL -lco OVERWRITE=YES -i 50 -nln new_isolines dem.tif "PG:host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mybase user=postgres password=postgres"**
I get a wrong usage message.

I know I can do it with ALTER/DROP table in my db prior to contouring with gdal, but that's unconvenient, because I want to set some more layer creation options:
**OVERWRITE=YES**
**GEOMETRY_NAME=wgsgeom**
**FID=id**
So how do I set theese options in gdal_contour utility?

Comment: I think you cannot have both -lco and -nln is the same command.

Comment: Maybe so, but removing -nln doesn't let me put -lco

Comment: Did you put the -loc param multiple times for each of the options?

Comment: Sure, doesn't work anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug was fixed in [r25643](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/changeset/25643).